# Host files in network directory in IIS

Tags: iis

On our network we have a dir with a lot of documents. These documents are invoice pdf's and I want to host these files with a webserver, so that I will be able to download them with a link like: `http://hostname:/invoicefilename.pdf`

We already have another application which is supposed to retrieve the invoices with the links we're building up.

I already used the HFS webserver (opensource) for this purpose, but that one is only able to host from a local folder. Is it possible in IIS to host a network drive, something like `//networkdrive/invoices` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in IIS you can host files from a network drive, however, you may have to add the network path trust like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11586520/1992193